# JQuery Select All Chekboxes Using Label For

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox

I am using a jquery plugin called magic-check, to create styled checkboxes. The checkboxes are displayed using the following example code:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="magic-checkbox" value="4140" id="4140" name="chc">
<label for="4140"></label>
```

I am having issues creating a select all button. I think the css on magic-check hides the checkbox and styles the label. I have tried numerous methods to solve, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure javaScript you can write:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.magic-checkbox[type="checkbox"]').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
        ele.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
```

});

Instead, in jQuery you can write:

```
$(':checkbox.magic-checkbox').prop('checked', 'checked');
```

An example:

```js
$('#selectall').on('click', function(e) {
    $(':checkbox.magic-checkbox').prop('checked', 'checked');
});

$('#unSelectall').on('click', function(e) {
    $(':checkbox.magic-checkbox').prop('checked', '');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/forsigner/magic-check/master/css/magic-check.min.css">


<div>
    <input class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="layout" id="1">
    <label for="1">Normal</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="layout" id="2" checked="checked">
    <label for="2">Checked</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="layout" id="3" disabled="disabled">
    <label for="3">
        Disabled
    </label>
</div>

<div>
    <input class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="layout" id="4" checked disabled="disabled">
    <label for="4">Checked && Disabled</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="magic-checkbox" value="4140" id="4140" name="chc">
    <label for="4140"></label>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<button type="button" id="selectall">Select all checkboxes</button>
<button type="button" id="unSelectall">Unselect all checkboxes</button>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Worked perfectly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution will scan your page for labels and check the corresponding input with a matching id. The second and third solutions are just efficient ways of checking all your check boxes on the page.

```js
$('#check-all').on('click', function(){
  $('label').each( function() {
    var target = $(this).attr('for');
    $('input[id="' + target + '"]').prop('checked', true);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="1">1</label>
<input id="1" type="checkbox"/>

<label for="2">2</label>
<input id="2" type="checkbox"/>

<button id="check-all">Check All</button>
```

Solution: Checking all check boxes on the page with Vanilla JS.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var button = document.getElementById('check-all');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  for ( var input in inputs ) {
    inputs[input].checked = true;
  }
})
```

```html
<label for="1">1</label>
<input id="1" type="checkbox"/>

<label for="2">2</label>
<input id="2" type="checkbox"/>

<button id="check-all">Check All</button>
```

Solution: Checking all check boxes on the page with jQuery.

```js
$('#check-all').on('click', function(){
  $('input').each( function() {
    this.checked = true;
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="1">1</label>
<input id="1" type="checkbox"/>

<label for="2">1</label>
<input id="2" type="checkbox"/>

<button id="check-all">Check All</button>
```